# Sorted and Paged ASP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, pagedlist

I am trying to setup search,paging, and sorting in my ASP.NET MVC5 application. I keep getting the following error...The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'. I am following the Microsoft Guide... (http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

What am I missing? It seems pretty straight forward.

```
public class npsAAA_dataController : Controller
{
    private npsAAAEntities db = new npsAAAEntities();

    // GET: npsAAA_data
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

        if (searchString != null)
            page = 1;
        else
            searchString = currentFilter;

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
        var user = from s in db.accounting_data select s;

        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            user = user.Where(s => s.User_Name.Contains(searchString));
        }
        switch(sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                user = user.OrderByDescending(s => s.User_Name);
                break;
            case "Date":
                user = user.OrderBy(s => s.timestamp);
                break;
            case "date_desc":
                user = user.OrderByDescending(s => s.timestamp);
                break;
            default:
                user = user.OrderBy(s => s.User_Name);
                break;

        }
        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(db.accounting_data.ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning your sorted data in the `return View()` line. Your current code is assigning the sorted data to `user`, but then you ignore it and instead call the database again to return unsorted data. Change your code into this instead:

```
return View(user.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```